# Shell script: inject command into existing running terminal process

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I have a situation where there is a running terminal process. I can find the PID of the terminal. I want to inject a command s.t. it runs and prints output in the target terminal process. I tried the following:

```
# Assuming terminal with PID is running in a different window
$ echo "ls\n" > /proc/PID/fd/0
```

This just prints the string in the second terminal window. How can I send a command (like ls) and then an enter key press into the second terminal window ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have `xdotool` installed ;

```
$ xdotool search --pid 2981 # 2981 being the PID of terminal, not shell
60817444
$ xdotool windowfocus --sync 60817444  type $'ls\n'
```